How to migrate to the app directory in Next Js
I have been following a tutorial which uses the /pages directory, however, the newer versions of NextJS are using the /app directory. How to adapt the following pages into the new behavior.
/pages/index.tsx
import Head from "next/head";
import { useState } from "react";
import Body from "../components/Body";
import Header from "../components/Layout/Header";
import { UploadImage } from "../components/UploadImage";
import { useData } from "../contexts/DataContext";

export default function Home() {
  let [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const { loading } = useData();

  function closeModal() {
    setIsOpen(false);
  }

  function openModal() {
    setIsOpen(true);
  }

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-start min-h-screen py-2">
      <Head>
        <title>Decentragram</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <UploadImage isOpen={isOpen} closeModal={closeModal} />
      <Header />
      <div
        className="max-w-2xl w-full bg-blue-100 rounded-xl flex justify-center items-center py-2 mt-3 hover:bg-blue-200 cursor-pointer"
        onClick={openModal}
      >
        <span className="text-blue-500 font-bold text-lg">Upload Image</span>
      </div>
      {loading ? (
        <div className="font-bold text-gray-400 mt-36 text-4xl">Loading...</div>
      ) : (
        <Body />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

pages/_app.tsx
import "tailwindcss/tailwind.css";
import { DataProvider } from "../contexts/DataContext";
import React from 'react';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: any) {
  return (
    <>
      <DataProvider>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </DataProvider>
    </>
  );
}

export default MyApp;

The full source code: Peer to Peer Donation dApp

You should read this in the docs:
From Pages to App

In the new version of Next.js, you have to understand React Server Component(RSC) and App Router.
I don't know this work, but it theoretically follows the new version of Next.js.
src/app/page.tsx

I prefer to locate src dir on top of app dir.

`use client`

import "tailwindcss/tailwind.css";
import { DataProvider } from "../contexts/DataContext";
import YourComponent from "../components/your-component";

export default function Page(){
  return (
    <>
      <DataProvider>
        <YourComponent />
      </DataProvider>
    </>
}

src/components/your-component.tsx
import Head from "next/head";
import { useState } from "react";
import Body from "../components/Body";
import Header from "../components/Layout/Header";
import { UploadImage } from "../components/UploadImage";
import { useData } from "../contexts/DataContext";

export default function YourComponent() {
  let [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const { loading } = useData();

  function closeModal() {
    setIsOpen(false);
  }

  function openModal() {
    setIsOpen(true);
  }

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-start min-h-screen py-2">
      <Head>
        <title>Decentragram</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <UploadImage isOpen={isOpen} closeModal={closeModal} />
      <Header />
      <div
        className="max-w-2xl w-full bg-blue-100 rounded-xl flex justify-center items-center py-2 mt-3 hover:bg-blue-200 cursor-pointer"
        onClick={openModal}
      >
        <span className="text-blue-500 font-bold text-lg">Upload Image</span>
      </div>
      {loading ? (
        <div className="font-bold text-gray-400 mt-36 text-4xl">Loading...</div>
      ) : (
        <Body />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}


I'm getting this error: Creating an optimized production build ...  ⨯ page.tsx doesn't have a root layout. To fix this error, make sure every page has a root layout.

You have to scaffold by ‘npx create-next-app@latest’, then apply my suggestion. It’s impossible to provide all related code for latest next.js app.
